# How can I integrate Nuxeo into netbeans or Eclipse to make a new application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, nuxeo

I am new to use Nuxeo plugin. I want to know how can we integrate Nuxeo in eclipse or netbeans to make a new application.

Comment: What do you want to "integrate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for an integration of Nuxeo within an IDE in order to ease Nuxeo plugin writing?
If so, you can [install the Nuxeo IDE plugin for Eclipse](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/g4KE). It provides an environment and features adapted to Nuxeo projects: dedicated perspective and views, Nuxeo SDKs, Nuxeo nature on Eclipse projects, auto-configuration (format, templates, ...), Hot reload, Nuxeo Shell, synchronization with Nuxeo Studio, POM synchronization, export JAR, more than 15 creation wizards, ...
There is also a [Nuxeo IntelliJ IDEA plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=7162) (with however less features than in the Eclipse plugin).

Comment: I installed successfully Nuxeo IDE on Eclipse. I want to know the steps to create my own application with Nuxeo. I have an internship where I should create an ECM application I prefer to use Nuxeo IDE to do my work.

Comment: Then you should follow the [Tutorials](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/dABu), starting from [NXDOC/Creating your project in Nuxeo IDE](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/ponZ).  

Also note the [Nuxeo Blog Tutorials](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/d4MlAQ) which address a lot of use cases, often answering questions asked on [Nuxeo Answers](http://answers.nuxeo.com/).